# In a Bootstrap 5 toast how can I align the Close button to the right?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, right-align, bootstrap-toast

I define a Bootstrap 5 toast like this:

```
<div id="liveToast" class="toast hide" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="toast-header">
        <strong class="me-auto">Help</strong>
        <button type="button" class="end-0 close" data-dismiss="toast">
            <span>&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

hoping the **`end-0`** class would align the Close button character `&times;` to the right border of the toast. Instead the class does nothing. Other placement classes like `m-2` do work.

Can I do this with a Bootstrap placement class or do I have to add manual CSS for this?

Comment: The close button is by default aligned to the right. And why are you using half BS-4 and half BS-5 code?

Comment: @MrUpsidown Ups, thanks for pointing this out.! By accident I had mixed bs-4 and bs-5 code. I now upgraded everything to bs-5 and, indeed, the button is automatically on the right. :-) -- Do you want to make this into an answer?

Comment: I'd say this is not reproducible / typo. You can delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The close button is by default aligned to the right (as @MrUpsidown pointed out in a comment). The problem had appeared, because I was using both BS-4 and half BS-5 code.

Converting everything to BS-5 code aligned the Close Button to the right.

Answer (score -1):

use 'float-end' Bootstrap 5 class to move the element to the right side.
For Bootstrap 4, use 'pull-right' or 'float-right' class.
It seems you are using Bootstrap 4.

```
<div id="liveToast" class="toast hide" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
<div class="toast-header">
    <strong class="me-auto">Help</strong>
    <button type="button" class="float-end close" data-bs-dismiss="toast">
        <span>&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
...
```

Comment: No code, no formatting, no explanation : -1.

Comment: @MrUpsidown what explanation do you need by only using a single bootstrap float class?

Comment: Me? Nothing. OP and the community might need some. Btw. the questions shouldn't even have been answered since the issue is non-existent, but if you place an answer, make it good quality. Provide code and explain what the code does and how it will fix the issue. One good way to provide code is by creating a runnable code snippet. For example, I still don't know if your code targets Bootstrap 4 or 5. Adding a code snippet with the library import would have clarified it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the "justify-content-between" class to the "toast-header" class. This will align the close button to the right. Here's how you can do it:

```
<div class="toast-header justify-content-between">
    <strong class="me-auto">Toast Header</strong>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes no difference. The close button is already aligned to the right.

Comment: Before applying 'justify-content-between' make sure to apply 'd-flex'.

Comment: The toast-header class, which is a part of Bootstrap, already uses flexbox by default.